# Move item position in mermaid flow chart

Tags: markdown, mermaid

I am writing a markdown flowchat with mermaid.

with this code

```
flowchart TB
    c1-->a2
    subgraph one
    a1-->a2
    end
    subgraph two
    b1-->b2
    end
    subgraph three
    c1-->c2
    end
    one --> two
    three --> two
    two --> c2
```

And we will get a flow chart like this

[image]

If I wanna move the c1 down a bit , make c1 align horizontally with a2 , Is there any way to do this?

And is there any way to modify each line's length?